# Update listbox asynchronously winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, reactive-programming

I'd like to insert a lot of elements into a `ListBox` with as much responsivity I can get. For this purpose I set up a generator, which produces `string`s. I'd like to add the new items in 100 millisec windows, not block the UI and using some kind of Task pool (`Scheduler.Default` in current case).

Reactive come to my mind, because it features every requirement.

```
// Use binding, rather than control.Items.Add, so the elements can be added on simultanious tasks, without working on the Form's thread.
private readonly BindingList<string> elements = new BindingList<string>();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindingSource source = new BindingSource {DataSource = elements};
    listBox1.DataSource = source;
    // works, but this way the window is useless.
    //listBox1.BeginUpdate();
    // generates 500 items to add into the listbox
    Observable.Generate(0L, x => x < 500, x => x + 1,
        y => "Current thread : " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId) // show which thread the item is generated
        .Window(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1d)) // supposedly makes UI unblock every 100 millisec
        .ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default) // supposedly generate elements on the "thread pool"
        .Subscribe(
            x =>
            {
                x.Subscribe(s => elements.Add(s));
            } /* , () =>
            {
                // for this we need System.Reactive.Windows.Forms
                ControlScheduler scheduler = new ControlScheduler(this);
                scheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0L), () => listBox1.EndUpdate());
            } */);
}
```

My problem is that, it shows the same thread id for each row. So the elements are not generated on `Scheduler.Default`. I expect to be able to change focus each 100 millisec, but not working.

EDIT

I tried with background worker approach too

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    // tried with elements volatile.
    BindingSource source = new BindingSource {DataSource = elements};
    listBox1.DataSource = source;
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Observable.Generate(0L, x => x < 500, x => x + 1,
        y => "Current thread : " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
        .Window(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1d))
        .ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default)
        .Subscribe(
            window =>
            {
                window.Subscribe(s => elements.Add(s),
                    () => backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(1)
                    );
            });
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // doesn't work. No elements showing. Something must be notified, but couldn't make it working
    listBox1.Refresh();
}
```

This approach is not much different, just it needs boilerplate code of background worker, and guaranteed doesn't block UI.

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234735/responsive-gui-using-multi-threading-in-c-sharp-winforms

Comment: thanks @StinkyTowel, but here not the task itself taking a lot of time (in the link the data came from database), but the filling into the listbox. BackgroundWorker states, that we shouldn't add items in the listbox directly> "You must be careful not to manipulate any user-interface objects in your DoWork event handler. Instead, communicate to the user interface through the BackgroundWorker events." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: On backgroundworker_progress - you can do list box manipulations

Comment: I believe C# 8's AsyncEnumerable will be the solution.