# Is There Any Way To Preload A Form

Tags: c#

I have made an windows form, with an initializing (form) which later redirects to the main form. The problem is it takes about three seconds to load, which make the user interface look really bad. The buttons are white, until they load, then they show the text and the colors. Is there any way to pre-load the form, but hide it, until the initializing (form) is finished?

For those who ask why it takes so long, I have a web browser which imports local HTML and it has InvokeText and addBase, addMaths and other items

This is the load script, how it loads the web browser

```
    private async void TextEdit_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {               
       WebClient wc = new WebClient();
       wc.Proxy = null;
       try
       {
            RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);
            string friendlyName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;
            bool flag2 = registryKey.GetValue(friendlyName) == null;
            if (flag2)
            {
                registryKey.SetValue(friendlyName, 11001, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            }
            registryKey = null;
            friendlyName = null;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(string.Format("file:///{0}/Files/TextEditor/Editor.html", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()));
```

The next bit is the functionality of the web browser

```
await Task.Delay(500);
        webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("SetTheme", new string[]
        {
               "Dark" 

        });
        addBase();
        addMath();
        addGlobalNS();
        addGlobalV();
        addGlobalF();
        webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("SetText", new object[]
        {
             ""
        });



    }
```

I guess it is the problem with the webBrowser (text editor) because when I delete it, it no longer takes 3 seconds loading time.

For those who say use `This.Hide();` and `This.Show();`, it does not work, because the web browser won't load at all.

Comment: there have to be a reason for such a long loading time. What are you doing in the loading event? or the constructor?

Comment: @MongZhu Those both event happen _before_ it's shown though; unless the long process is moved to a separate loading thread, with the form displaying a "Loading" message or progress bar, the Constructor or Load event would be the preferred place to _migrate_ those long load times to.

Comment: I would recommend trying to make the form show as fast as possible without any of its (large) data or images, and then load it all in the `Form_Shown` event. More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/order-of-events-in-windows-forms. If needed use background processing. An app that does nothing and shows nothing for seconds is a bad experience.

Comment: @PeterB um, wouldn't that be exactly what would _cause_ an unresponsive UI while loading? Form_Shown is processed in the UI thread, after the form is shown. It locks up the form's refresh.

Comment: @Nyerguds I updated my comment - just guidelines, no absolute solutions.

Comment: @PeterB Well, to avoid unresponsiveness on long loads, the _only_ real solution is using multithreading while showing some kind of "please wait" message. This question is too broad though; as Mong Zhu remarked from the start, it gives no information whatsoever about what may be slowing down the loading.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234735/responsive-gui-using-multi-threading-in-c-sharp-winforms)

Answer (score 2):

if the main issue is that `it takes about three seconds to load`, then consider **Threading** on your form's `Load` event (provided you placed all pre-requisite loading there). This way you can initially disable controls prior to the form being displayed and enable controls once the entire process is finished. See below example:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    #region Disable controls here
    textbox1.Enabled = false;
    button1.Enabled = false;
    combobox1.Enabled = false;
    #endregion

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        try
        {
            // Do Long running processing of form prerequisites here.

            ...

            // Enable controls here once processing is sucessful and complete.

            Invoke((Action) (() => {
                textbox1.Enabled = true;
                button1.Enabled = true;
                combobox1.Enabled = true;        
            }));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Invoke((Action) (() => {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }));
        }    
    });
}
```

Comment: What does "Do Long running processing of form prerequisites here" mean?

Comment: that's *whatever-your-code-is-doing* that makes it finish in no less than 3 seconds.

Comment: The thing is, I already have items in Form1_Load and it's a private async void